# Bootstrap Dropdowns will expand, but not close when included as asp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap navigation bar that works perfectly in its own html file. The dropdowns on this file will open and close like they should. I want to include this file onto my other pages so that I don't have to update every single page's navigation bar if I ever change it. I have chosen to do this through using server side includes. My other pages are saved as asp files to allow for server side includes.

When I use

```
<!-- #include virtual="/navigation.html" -->
```

the dropdowns in the navigation are able to be expanded, but they will not go back up. Any ideas what may be going wrong?

Comment: That's a JS issue, not a server side include issue. Maybe your JS was modified when you moved from prototype into functional site?

Comment: It could be, I'm pretty new to coding. I have the correct script files on the page that I am trying to include the file on, they are at the bottom of the html before the closing body tag.

Comment: @staypuftman I think you could be right, something is going wrong with the javascript. The navigation include doesn't seem to be using the javascript that it needs... I don't know how to fix this though :(

Comment: Figure out where in the process your server side system incorporates JS and update it with the JS from your prototype. What are you using? Most likely there is some kind of master file template, check that out.

Comment: I just realized that none of the elements on my website that require javascript are working. Everything was working fine until I decided to convert all my pages to .asp so that I could include my navigation bar. Is there a special way to include javascript into a page in asp or a certain place that it needs to go? Ex) in the header, before closing body tag, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. My include files only needed the html code, no links to javascript, css, or opening and closing html,head, or body tags.

Comment: Makes sense, glad you figured it out.